# GET request is showing "406 - Not Acceptable" in Dart for http package Flutter

Tags: flutter, http, dart, get, header

I am requesting the following Get request but getting "406 - Not Acceptable" response. Here I have attached the request code:

```
final Map<String, String> tokenData = {"Authorization": token};

var response = await http.get(url, headers: tokenData);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
  var itemCount = jsonResponse['totalItems'];
  print('Number of books about http: $itemCount.');
} else {
  print('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}.');
  print('Request failed with reason: ${response.reasonPhrase}.');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your **tokenData**  as follow:

```
 final Map<String, String> tokenData = {
    'Authorization': token
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  };
```

It will work if you are getting JSON as a response.